# Ajuda com Array e operações

Tags: javascript, array, lógica

Array[1] previamente setado.

A lógica é, pegar o ultimo numero do Array, fazer a operação com o valor do display e retornar como ultimo numero do array.

**Exemplo:**

Digite 2 e aperte `X`, 2 * o ultimo item do array.  Retorna 2.
Então este valor é jogado para o final do Array.

Agora Array[1,2]. Aperte 4 e multiplique, Array[1,2,8].

Estou contente com isso pois posso manipular depois.

A questão é este Array previamente setado com 1 deveria estar vazio!!! Pois assim eu poderia reutilizar este calculo para divisão.

Já que se você testar a mesma coisa com o botao de divisao (Aperta A/C antes). Aperta 2 %, Ai está, o Array ficara Array[1,0.5]. pois 1/2= 0.5.

Daria certo se fosse 2/1, pois resultaria em Array[1,2], e daria certo.

Já tentei iniciar Array com valor null, 0 e ''. Sempre retorna `NaN`, `undefined` ou o proprio `0`, obviamente.

Lembre de digitar o numero no display e so clicar em X, A/C para resetar o Array e %.

```js
const buttonnum = document.getElementsByClassName('num');
    const inputdisplay = document.querySelector('#displayval input[type="text"]')
    var arrayhistory = [1];
    var resultado;
    Array.from(buttonnum).forEach(function(item) {
      item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        switch (e.target.value) {
          case "A/C":
            arrayhistory = [1];
            inputdisplay.value = "0";
            console.log(arrayhistory);
            break;
          case "C":
            inputdisplay.value = inputdisplay.value.slice(0, -1);
            if (inputdisplay.value == '') {
              inputdisplay.value = "0";
            }
            break;
          case "X":
            var arraylastnum = arrayhistory.slice(-1)[0];
            console.log(arraylastnum);
            resultado = (arraylastnum * inputdisplay.value)
            arrayhistory.push(resultado);
            inputdisplay.value = '0';
            console.log(arrayhistory);
            break;
          case ".":
            inputdisplay.value += '.';
            break;
          case "%":
            var arraylastnum = arrayhistory.slice(-1)[0];
            console.log(arraylastnum);
            resultado = (arraylastnum / inputdisplay.value);
            arrayhistory.push(resultado);
            inputdisplay.value = '0';
            console.log(arrayhistory);
            break;
          case "-":
            break;
          case "√":
            break;
          case "+":
            break;
          case "÷":
            break;
          case "=":
            break;
        }
      })
    })
```

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    header h1 {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 8px;
    }

    #div-caldisplay {
      background-color: rgb(51, 51, 48);
      width: 500px;
      height: 140px;
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 20px;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }

    #displayval {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 80px;
    }

    #text-view {
      height: 75px;
      width: 470px;
      font-size: 35px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .flexcontainer {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-content: space-around;
      background-color: rgb(18, 58, 18);
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      height: 350px;
      width: 300px;
      margin-left: 31.8%;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }

    .flexcontainer2 {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: space-around;
      background-color: rgb(158, 27, 27);
      border-radius: 8px;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      height: 350px;
      width: 100px;
    }

    .flexcontainer3 {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: space-around;
      background-color: rgb(2, 2, 2);
      border-radius: 8px;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      height: 350px;
      width: 100px;
    }

    #flex {
      display: flex;
    }

    #teste1 {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: darkmagenta;
    }

    #teste2 {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: chartreuse;
    }

    .num {
      width: 85px;
      height: 65px;
      font-size: 25px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
      transition-duration: 0.1s;
    }

    .num:active {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .num:hover {
      font-size: 28px;
    }

    #mais {
      height: 195px;
      background-color: crimson;
    }

    #igual {
      height: 195px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calc.css">

    <body>

      <main>
        <div id="div-caldisplay">
          <header>
            <h1>CALCULATOR</h1>
          </header>

          <div id="displayval">
            <input type="text" name="visor" value="0" id="text-view">
          </div>

        </div>
        <div id="flex">
          <div class="flexcontainer">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="A/C">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="C">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="X">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="1">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="2">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="3">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="4">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="5">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="6">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="7">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="8">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="9">
            <input class="num" type="button" value=".">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="0">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="00">
          </div>
          <div class="flexcontainer2 ">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="%">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="-">
            <input class="num" id="plus" type="button" value="+">

          </div>
          <div class="flexcontainer3">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="√">
            <input class="num" type="button" value="÷">
            <input class="num" id="equals" type="button" value="=">

          </div>
        </div>


      </main>
      <script src="calcjs.js"></script>
    </body>


    </html>
```

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui !
A solução para % foi essa:

```
 case "%":
            var arraylastnum = arrayhistory.slice(-1)[0];
            console.log(arraylastnum);
            if (arraylastnum == 1) {
                resultado = (inputdisplay.value / arraylastnum);
            }
            else {
                resultado = (arraylastnum / inputdisplay.value);
            }
            arrayhistory.push(resultado);
            inputdisplay.value = '0';
            console.log(arrayhistory);
            break;
```

Com + e - da pra iniciar com o valor 0 No Array Array[0]. Porém vamos ver na radiciação e porcentagem.